# How do I add an input tag to a form using HTML Agility Pack?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, html-agility-pack

I start off with a set of forms:

```
<form action="/Test/1">
    <p>This is my 1st form.</p>
    <button type="submit">Submit Form</button>
</form>

<form action="/Test/2">
    <div>This is my 2nd form.</div>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit Form" />
    <input type="hidden" name="var1" value="123" />
</form>
```

And I attempt to add an input tag to all forms on the page:

```
HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(inputHtml); // inputHtml is a string containing the forms above
var nodes = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//form");
if (nodes != null)
{
    foreach (var node in nodes)
    {
        node.AppendChild(HtmlNode.CreateNode("<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"var2\" value=\"456\" />"));
    }
}
var model = doc.DocumentNode.OuterHtml;
```

This is what I was expecting:

```
<form action="/Test/1">
    <p>This is my 1st form.</p>
    <button type="submit">Submit Form</button>
    <input type="hidden" name="var2" value="456">
</form>

<form action="/Test/2">
    <div>This is my 2nd form.</div>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit Form">
    <input type="hidden" name="var1" value="123">
    <input type="hidden" name="var2" value="456">
</form>
```

However, this is what I get as a result: *(line breaks and spacing added for readability)*

```
<form action="/Test/1">
    <input type="hidden" name="var2" value="456">
</form>
    <p>This is my 1st form.</p>
    <button type="submit">Submit Form</button>
</form>

<form action="/Test/2">
    <input type="hidden" name="var2" value="456">
</form>
    <div>This is my 2nd form.</div>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit Form">
    <input type="hidden" name="var1" value="123">
</form>
```

Now I have duplicate `</form>` closing tags.

What is the proper way to achieve the desired result using HTML Agility Pack?

**Update:** 2nd form in expected results had a bug in it showing the duplicate form tag. (Copy-paste error)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just call `HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode.ElementsFlags.Remove("form");` before you load your document, after that append should work as you expect.

**on a side node:**

why bother skipping double quotes when you can write it as:

```
"<input type='hidden' name='var2' value='456'/>"
```

Comment: Was hoping for a less hacky solution because this is altering static data, but it works and hasn't broken anything else yet.  As far as the side note, I did it because I like my HTML output to look like one unified style, even if it's just demo code.